# how do use RESTSHARP send parameter JSON in this formatted JSON sub

Tags: c#, .net, json, restsharp

I use c# and use Restsharp in method  request.AddBody() I want to this format

```
{
"boss":[{
"cus":"454",
"date":"July 23,2015",
"mangpo":"9.1",
"namo":"rattatrayaya"
}]
}
```

But my code:

```
              request.AddBody( new { 
boss = new []{"cus":"454","date":"July23,2015","mangpo":"9.1","namo":"rattatrayaya"}   });
```

out put json to sent wrong not have "[":

```
"boss":{
"cus":"454",
"date":"July 23,2015",
"mangpo":"9.1",
"namo":"rattatrayaya"
}
```

how do sent in restsharp in this formatted. help me now!

Comment: do u want to post in json format..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
request.AddBody(new
            {
                boss = new []
                {
                    new { cus="454", date="July23,2015", mangpo="9.1", namo="rattatrayaya"}
                }

            });
```

or you can post direct json object like this...

```
request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8",
                "{\"boss\":[{\"cus\":\"454\",\"date\":\"July23,2015\",\"mangpo\":\"9.1\",\"namo\":\"rattatrayaya\"}]}",
                ParameterType.RequestBody);
```